# Using PHP to get current directory name?

Tags: php

I already know about `getcwd` but it doesn't really appear to do exactly what I'm wanting.  I'm trying to figure out how to get the name of the directory someone is currently in.

For example, if I was at `http://www.google.com/test/index.php?page=343` then what I am trying to get is `test` since that's the directory they are in.  What's the easiest way to do this with PHP?

Comment: Try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Comment: That url absolutely does NOT mean that `test` is the directory they are in.

Comment: try this: `basename(__DIR__)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like:

```
echo basename(__DIR__);
```

Howewer, this works only on PHP versions higher 5.3.

Comment: Someone seems to have something to complain about, explain the downvotes please.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo dirname(__FILE__);
```

If below PHP5

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing working directory/folder and path/URI/URL.

Directory is the folder on the computer, path is web address. They aren't always the same.

```
$bits = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
$piece = $bits[count($bits) - 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this magical constant and the output will depend where you use it.

```
__DIR__   

outputs the directory of the file, where you use the magic constatn.

 <?php 
       echo __DIR__;
?>
```

if you use this in 'http://www.google.com/test/index.php'  it will display the http://www.google.com/test/  directory as the current directory.